# CPU watch and email with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to setup an automatic email if the conditions are meet. I'm trying to watch my cpu load. if pass or drops over a number send a email.

`CheckCPULoad: 
  CoordMode, ToolTip, Screen 
  SetFormat, float, 0.0 
  CPULoad := GetCPULoad_Short() 
  ToolTip, CPULoad = %CPULoad%`%, 0 ,%A_ScreenHeight% 
  return

```
GetCPULoad_Short()
{ 
Static IdleTime, Tick 
global ProcessorCount
SetBatchLines, -1 
OldIdleTime = %IdleTime% 
OldTick = %Tick% 
VarSetCapacity( IdleTicks,8,0)
  DllCall("kernel32.dll\GetSystemTimes", "uint",&IdleTicks, "uint",0,   "uint",0) 
   IdleTime := *(&IdleTicks) 
Loop 7                    
  IdleTime += *( &IdleTicks + A_Index ) << ( 8 * A_Index ) 
Tick := A_TickCount 
Return 100 - 0.01*(IdleTime - OldIdleTime)/(Tick - OldTick) / ProcessorCount
}




 #############
#IfEqual, CPUload, 0, 
     #or
 if (CPUload = 0)
 {

  IfWinNotExist Inbox - Email@Email.com - Outlook
  return  ; Outlook isn't open to the right section, so do nothing.
  WinActivate  ; Activate the window found by the above command.
  Send ^n  ; Create new/blank e-mail via Control+N.
  WinWaitActive Untitled - Message (HTML)
  Send, sentEmailto@help.com
  Send {Tab 3} computer has stopped  ; Set the subject line.
  Send {Tab} more txt.  ; etc.
  return  ; This line serves to finish the hotkey.



 }
```

But I tried with a simple

if (CPULoad = 0)
msgBox testing

and it won't give me a message. why can i get a message box to show. or email to send?

Comment: You are using Outlook on this computer and it is up and running?  Note that AutoHotKey is probably not the best way to mange performance alerts...

Comment: yes its up and running.. and this is just a test to see if it will help us. we are sure to look into other options.. any suggestions? on open source that can look at cpu and send alerts if conditions are met

Comment: We use the paid version of datadoghq.com, though there is a free version that may suit you.

Comment: Heh, I'd use a batch file with the built-in [typeperf](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490960.aspx), which can measure CPU load over a specified period of time, and some command line email utility like BLAT.

Comment: BTW your syntax is funky: what's `#IfEqual` and `#or`? Are you using some nonstandard AHK?

Comment: no was just trying to add comments as i posted this

Comment: and will look into datadoghq...ps. only can use for 14 days free :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post got me curious to see if this had been done before and I instantly found a solution posted on the ahkscript forums:

```
Loop {
  If (CPULoad() > 25) ; Assign the Number you want. 
    ; Your EMAIL Code here! If MultiLine Use {...code...}
  Sleep 250
}

CPULoad() { ; By SKAN, CD:22-Apr-2014 / MD:05-May-2014. Thanks to ejor, Codeproject: http://goo.gl/epYnkO
Static PIT, PKT, PUT                           ; http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?p=17166#p17166
  IfEqual, PIT,, Return 0, DllCall( "GetSystemTimes", "Int64P",PIT, "Int64P",PKT, "Int64P",PUT )

  DllCall( "GetSystemTimes", "Int64P",CIT, "Int64P",CKT, "Int64P",CUT )
, IdleTime := PIT - CIT,    KernelTime := PKT - CKT,    UserTime := PUT - CUT
, SystemTime := KernelTime + UserTime 

Return ( ( SystemTime - IdleTime ) * 100 ) // SystemTime,    PIT := CIT,    PKT := CKT,    PUT := CUT 
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does allow me assign a number to the CPUload.. thank you for finding this